# AnimationDrawable doesn't autostart on Lollipop

Tags: android, animation

I have an Android App where looped AnimationDrawbale where autostarted. With latest Lollipop it doesn't autostart no more.

There is a simple ImageView where the src address the next drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_sun" />
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_cloudsun" />
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_cloud" />
    <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_rain" />
    <item android:maxLevel="4" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_rainstorm" />
</level-list>
```

each item of the level list is another drawable xml.
Some of them are animation-list (Animationdrawable), others are layer-list with one or more layer composed by an animation-list. Here an example:

```
<layer-list
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <animation-list android:oneshot="false">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_rain1" android:duration="100" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_rain2" android:duration="100" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_rain3" android:duration="100" />
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_rain4" android:duration="100" />
        </animation-list>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_cloudcolor1" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_cloud2" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_weather_layer_cloud1" />
</layer-list>
```

The ImageView level is set invisible at activity start and it is simply selected in this way.

```
    final ImageView meteo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_meteo);
    meteo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    meteo.setImageLevel( weatherIdx );
```

Any idea on th reason? And how I should manage that?
I cannot address all AnimationDrawables, because there are several of them in a not known structure.

Thanks

Comment: did you found the problem ?

Comment: No, simply Lollipop does not more auto-start animations. I managed that with a complicated loop of loop to start each animation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a class based on `AppCompatImageView` that will autostart both the source and background `AnimationDrawables`.

```
public class AnimationImageView extends AppCompatImageView
{
    public AnimationImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public AnimationImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimationImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundResource(@DrawableRes int resId)
    {
        super.setBackgroundResource(resId);
        startAnimation(getBackground());
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)
    {
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        startAnimation(background);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId)
    {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        startAnimation(getDrawable());
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(@Nullable Drawable drawable)
    {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        startAnimation(drawable);
    }

    protected void startAnimation(Drawable drawable)
    {
        if (drawable instanceof AnimationDrawable)
        {
            ((AnimationDrawable) drawable).start();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it in your layouts as follows (change `com.sample.ui.views` to match the package where you will place the class above):

```
<com.sample.ui.views.AnimationImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_src_animation"
    android:background="@drawable/my_bg_animation"/>
```

Comment: Nice idea to get it working automatically, but it does not solve exactly the problem I had. I had a structure of LeveList and LayerList and animation was embeded in it. So for doing it work wyou should change your startAnimation method and run it recursivelly for Drawables that may contain others (StateListDrawable, LevelListDrawable, LayerDrawable, InsetDrawable, etc...). More you should also override method setImageLevel, so animation will start even when you only change ImageLevel (that was the behaviour change I initially found in Lollipop).

Answer (score 1):

should just be able to cast it to an animation drawable and then click start.

```
((AnimationDrawable) imageview.getDrawable()).start();
```

not sure why there is a change in behavior on 5.0 but this does not change behavior on lower APIs

Comment: As I said be in my question, is not so simple, because outer drawable is not an AnimationDrawable, but it may be a complicated hierarchy of LayerListDrawable and LevelListDrawable. I solved with a recursive method.